# caret dummyVars on unseen data

Tags: machine-learning, r, dummy-variables

I created my dummy variables, trained my model and tested it as below:

```
dummy <- dummyVars(formula = CLASS_INV ~ ., data = campaign_spending_final_imputed) 
campaign_spending_final_dummy <- predict(dummy, newdata = campaign_spending_final_imputed) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(CLASS_INV = campaign_spending_final$CLASS_INV)
```

I now want to test my process on an unseen real world data. How can I do it? How can I encode the category class to its respective dummy encoding?

Answer (score 1):

The `predict` function will work on the new data.  It has some options for how to handle entries that don't appear in the original data's labels.

https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/dummyVars.html